# WiX Burn BA - download payloads behind OAUTH, and is there a possibility to change the UpdateLocation and re-run engine detect?

Tags: wix, auto-update, burn

I currently spike with WiX 3.11.2 to build a burn bootstrapping application that downloads packages from a local http server currently without any authentication.

Due to a lack of documentation of WiX burn I mostly reverse engineered how to set the UpdateLocation + how to check for updates via skimming through the UpdateViewModel.cs from the Wix3 repository.

As far as I have read, the

`Engine.SetDownloadSource(ea.PackageOrContainerId,ea.PayloadId, dlUrl,user,pass);`

can be used to download with no AUTH (last 2 parameters null) or plain authentication. Without authentication I already have a working prototype - but I will need the possibility to authenticate against a OAUTH secured web server.

If I were to need for instance to download behind a OAUTH2 authentication would the best practice be to use the `OnResolveSourdce` Event and instead of setting the Result to Result.Download, just do it myself with OAUTH2 libraries and download it to the `ea.LocalSource` so the engine basically thinks that the source has always been already available?

My second question is with regards to the UpdateLocation.
In the `OnDetectUpdateBegin` event I can set the ea.Result to Result.Ok if I want to check for upates - but I would like to be able to change the UpdateLocation during runtime, similar to what the Visual Studio Installer allows - to have different ReleaseFeeds, something like `PROD` or `TESTING` or `Preview`.

is there any possiblity to tell the Engine to set the UpdateLocation to a different URI? It would seem that the `OnDetectUpdateBegin` event would be perfect to change that, but the `ea.UpdateLocation` only has a Get, and I did not find a Engine.SetUpdate location or anything similar.

If I am not mistaken the VStudio installer is also built upon WiX so I would presume it should be somehow possible - am I missing something here?